# Derivative/gradient calculation for non structured data in python

Tags: python, numpy, derivative

I have a bunch of unstructured points in 3D and a function value at each one. I want to calculate the gradient of the function (first and second order derivatives) at each point. Is there somewhere (scipy, numpy,...) an implemented function for doing this?

Example (I'm looking for `some_function`):

```
import numpy as np
import random

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-50, 50, 50), np.linspace(-50, 50, 50))

x = np.array([i + random.random() for i in xx.flatten()])
y = np.array([i + random.random() for i in yy.flatten()])

z = x**2 + x*y

dzdx_analytic = 2*x + y
dzdy_analytic = x

dzdx_numeric, dzdy_numeric = some_function(z, [x, y])
```

I've found [numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) but don't understand the documentation enough to know if I can use it for this - I think it only works with structured data.

I could implement something like [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54562-gypaets-trigradient2) (least squares linear regression using all neighbouring points), but would prefer to use an already implemented function in a standard library, if possible.